# Is there a way to build images assets with Heroku in a Symfony app, without deleting images already upload through a form in back office?

Tags: heroku, deployment, compilation, symfony5.4

I have a Symfony app, deployed with Heroku.
In Heroku buildpacks I have "heroku/php" and "heroku/nodejs" to build assets such as SCSS / JS / images.
SCSS and JS are build into ***/public/build*** folder
Image are build into ***/public/uplaods/*** folder

The app is automatically deployed everytime I pushed to GitHub.
In a custom admin interface through form I can upload image for my profile user. (will be insert into the folder (***/public/uploads/profile/{picture_name}***)
But everytime I pushed new commits : Assets are rebuild and my already-uploaded-image are erased from the folder (but not in DB)

Do you know some scripts or any approach I can do to avoid this thing during compilation ?

I'm expecting a way , an approach to insert some script maybe, in order to not delete this subfolder.